# Return multi kinf of Object of Web Service in Java

Tags: java

I am using web service in Java.Here is my problem:

```
public Object execute(int servicecode)
{
    switch (servicecode)
    {
        case 1:
           return OBJECT_1;
        case 2:
           return OBJECT_2;
        case 3:
           return OBJECT_3;
    }
}
```

- My function returns OBJECT_1,OBJECT_2,OBJECT_3. I want client to understand:

  - case 1 Object=OBJECT_1
  - case 2 Object=OBJECT_2
  - case 3 Object=OBJECT_3

How can I do it in a Web Service? I tried to use inheritance in the Web Service but I can't get properties of OBJECT_1, OBJECT_2, OBJECT_3.

Comment: do you return deferent types of Objects? Lets say in case 1 you return a Person object and in case 2 a House object ? Or is it always the same type of object returned?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, If OBJECT_1,OBJECT_2,OBJECT_3 has different types then.. you can do it like..

---

```
public class Object {
// here we are creating a class who has all objects you want to return, 
    // this is called wrapper class
private Object_1 object_1;
private Object_2 object_1;
private Object_3 object_1;
public Object_1 getObject_1() {
    return object_1;
}
public void setObject_1(Object_1 object_1) {
    this.object_1 = object_1;
}
public Object_2 getObject_1() {
    return object_1;
}
public void setObject_1(Object_2 object_1) {
    this.object_1 = object_1;
}
public Object_3 getObject_1() {
    return object_1;
}
public void setObject_1(Object_3 object_1) {
    this.object_1 = object_1;
}
```

}

```
public class Test{ 
public Object execute(int servicecode)
{
    Object object = new Object();
    switch (servicecode)
    {
        case 1:
           return object.setObject_1(object_1);
        case 2:
           return object.setObject_2(object_2);;
        case 3:
           return object.setObject_3(object_3);;
    }
}
```

}